# Google Deployment Manager import files from a parent directory

Tags: google-deployment-manager

I can import files from a sub directory like this and it works:

```
my-app/
├── templates/
│   └── somefile.jinja
├── my-config.yaml

#my-config.yaml
imports:
  - path: templates/somefile.jinja
```

But if I try to access a file in a parent directory it fails:

```
my-app/
├── templates/
│   └── my-config.jinja
├── somefiles/
│   └── somefile.jinja

#my-config.yaml
imports:
  - path: ../somefiles/somefile.jinja
```

How do I go up a directory to import files?

Comment: As per [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/templates/create-basic-template#importing_the_template) you should be able to target imports using either relative or absolute paths. So this should work, though it might be a limitation of DM. I'm going to try it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using a relative path does work just as it would from your command line. The importnt part is that you have to keep using the full relative path anytime you want to call the template for a resource.

To use your example:

```
imports:
- path: ../somefiles/somefile.jinja

resources:
- name: someResource
  type: ../somefiles/somefile.jinja
```

Comment: ill add to my example but this still doesnt work for me. i should have said im actually importing a template but _also_ importing other files that template needs to use- maybe that case makes this different? totally works if they are in a child dir but not if they are in a parent dir

Comment: what are you importing in the template? I'm also wondering if the relative path from the template may need to be relative to the directory where you are running the config file from because of how deployment manager is expanding the template

Comment: one more note, you can add a `name` field to each path so that you can reference the name of the import instead of the full path